# Eclipse RCP E4 accessing other class

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

I have two Parts lets say A and B. Part A has a function named `isDragging` which returns boolean.

How can I access the `isDragging` function in method B ? Should I make the function become static ? Can I rely on Dependency Injection here (if it's possible) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `EModelService` to find Part A by its id:

```java
@Inject
EModelService modelService;
@Inject
MApplication application;


MPart partA = (MPart)modelService.find("part A id", application);

PartAObject myObject = (PartAObject)partA.getObject();

if (myObject.isDragging())
```

where 'PartAObject' is your part Class (as specified in the model Class URI).

Comment: Earlier I tried with `EPartService` however it feeds the whole UI into my other part. Thanks for sharing this.